# How to log by hours instead of minutes in CiviVolunteer

Tags: civivolunteer

Using CiviVolunteer Version 4.7.31-2.3.1 / CiviCRM 4.7.31

"Log Hours" and "Volunteer Report" have Duration in minutes instead of hours.

Is there a way to change to "Hours" instead? I tried Administer "Word Replacements" with the below but it doesn't seem to change all the instances.  The Reporting especially is still showing a label of minutes.

minutes / hours / exact match
  Minutes / Hours / exact match

I want to avoid volunteers getting confused by the difference in language, and volunteering is set by hours only, not minutes. Also for Reporting the managers want to see hours.